# Why the snapshot.data.documents can't be accessed while getting messages from Cloud Firestore through StreamBuilder?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

The `snapshot.data.documents` can't be accessed while getting messages from Cloud Firestore through `StreamBuilder`.

Code:

```
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data['sender'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );

          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Error:

> The property 'documents' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.

[image]

Is there any way to solve this bug or any other way in which my method can be successfully implemented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to make change on the lines

```
builder: (context, snapshot)
```

to

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot)
```

then use

```
snapshot.data as snapshot.data!.
```

Code:

```
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data!.docs;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message['text'];
          final messageSender = message['sender'];

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: loggedInUser.email == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final messages = snapshot.data?.docs.reversed;

    List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles =[];
    for( var message in messages!){
      var data = message.data() as Map;
      final messageText = data['text'];
      final messageSender = data['sender'];

      final currentUser = loggedInUser?.email;


      final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
          sender: messageSender,
          text: messageText,
          isME: currentUser == messageSender,
      );
      messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
```